# NOTEPAD++ , How to insert some character to special characters

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, characters

How do I get:

```
blablabla x/11/1048.1 blablabla blablabla
x/11/i blablabla
blablablax/11/a
&nbsp;blablabla x/11/b.2 blablabla blablabla blablabla
```

to become:

```
x/11/1048.1.full.y
x/11/i.full.y
x/11/a.full.y
x/11/b.2.full.y
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64256/discussion-on-question-by-michael-andrew-notepad-how-to-insert-some-characte).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(x/[^/]+/\S+).*$`
- Replace with: `$1.full.y`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
.*?             : 0 or more any character, not greedy
(               : start group 1
  x             : literally x
  /             : literally /
  [^/]+         : 1 or more any character that is not /
  /             : literally /
  \S+           : 1 or more character that is not a space
)               : end group 1
.*              : 0 or more any character
$               : end of line
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Replacement:**

```
$1.full.y       : content of group 1 followed by .full.y
```

**Result for given example:**

```
x/11/1048.1.full.y
x/11/i.full.y
x/11/a.full.y
x/11/b.2.full.y
```

Answer (score 0):

We are just adding `.full.y` to the end of the line, after we move sequences of `blablabla`.

First, do a search replace that removes all instances of 'blablabla' (with variations to remove extra spaces).

Then, use a regular expressions, as `$` means "the end of the line":

[image]

Comment: sorry my bad, I was edit my question, please solve the problem, best regards

Comment: looking at his latest edit which in fairness to you, he made after you posted your answer, you haven't removed the blahblah

Comment: I have updated this answer to take the question literally.  I expect there will be a further clarifying edit.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have

```
blablabla x/11/1048.1 blablabla blablabla
x/11/i blablabla
blablablax/11/a
 blablabla x/11/b.2 blablabla blablabla blablabla
```

It doesn't matter what text blahbla is.

find `.*(x/[^/]*/[^/\s\b]*[\s\b]).*`

replace with \1

The part in the round brackets of the find, is your x/..../... pattern, that you want to retain.

gives

```
x/11/1048.1 
x/11/i 
x/11/a
x/11/b.2
```

I find some of them have spaces after them, which could be a flaw with my regex but it doesn't matter,   we can find the space at the end of the line and remove it.

find: `(\r?\n)`   <-- that is, find space character followed by a line separator or line terminator,  \r\n or \n, and replace with just the line separator or line terminator. We will remove the space from that.

replace with:  `\1`

```
x/11/1048.1 
x/11/i 
x/11/a
x/11/b.2
```

And this finds every line that starts with an x/ and 'captures it' and replaces it with itself followed by .full.y

find: `(^x/.*$)`
replace with `\1.full.y`

```
x/11/1048.1.full.y
x/11/i.full.y
x/11/a.full.y
x/11/b.2.full.y
```